# How to monitor/log sql time from kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I have some containers running in kubernetes in the cloud, these are querying on prem db servers, I'm interested in seeing how the latencies from the dbs are affecting the app. How would I go about monitoring/logging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I just want to graph SGBD response times, I could setup some Pod that would query my database on a loop, and output some result to its stdout, ... some kind of `time mysql <cmd-args>`. Then, I would use a prometheus library exposing those metrics (or munin, collectd, ... whatever fits in your ecosystem).

Assuming I'm interested in SQL internal metrics, I could deploy some mysql exporter on Kubernetes, querying a remote SGBD. Though I doubt you would have much data regarding link latency.

Assuming I'm not much interested in MySQL itself, rather in site-to-site latency, I could use something like smokeping, graphing response times. Better: some kind of TCP check, not necessarily querying MySQL, rather measuring how long you would need to establish a TCP handshake.

Though, the ideal case would be for your application to measure those times. Slow responses could be due to distance, as well as hardware failures, or software mishaps. It could make sense to track both query times and queried data, as you may be able to pinpoint queries that can be optimized, ...

Oh, and obviously, Istio, Service Meshes, .... tend to come with lots of tools that would help you track execution times, data flows, ...